# How to build stopwatch with hundreth of a second precision?

Tags: java, time, datetime-format, runnable

I'm trying to build a stopwatch with hundreth of second precision. I have this code that runs every 10 milliseconds but I am having trouble converting it to a 0(min):0(sec):00 format.

```
timer.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        time += 1;
        txtView.setText(convertTimeToText(time));
        timer.postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
});

private String convertTimeToText(int time) {
    String convertedTime = time / 6000 + ":" + (time / 100) % 60
            + ":" + (time / 10) % 10 + time % 10;
    return convertedTime;
}
```

I need help with the convertTimeToText(int time){} that formats time.

EDIT:
Thanks to Ole V.V. and WJS for the formatting answer and how to fix the delay I was having, this is the code I came up with if anybody needs it, so far it works well, maybe using System.nanoTime() will get you more accurate results but for my use its fine.

```
public void start(){
        final long timeMillisWhenStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(!isRunning){
            isRunning = true;
            timer.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     long millisNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                     long time = millisNow - timeMillisWhenStarted;
                    yourtxtView.setText(convertTimeToText(time));
                    timer.postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
        }
    }

private String convertTimeToText(long time){
        long hundredths = time  / 10;
        long sec = hundredths / 100;
        long min = sec / 60;

        return String.format("%02d:%02d.%02d", min % 60, sec % 60, hundredths % 100);

        }
```

Comment: @Nicknackd Please don't post your code in comments.  Just edit your post in response to suggested edits.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for. How is it  not working as you expect?

Comment: I would expect this to work but when I execute the program I get a consistent cummulative delay and I can not find out why.

Comment: As an aside, most users in the world will expect a decimal separator (either point or comma) between the seconds and the fraction of second, not a colon.

Comment: Thanks for providing your own solution. Two suggestions: (1) Post it as an answer rather than as an edit to your question. More people will find it, and it will be more helpful. (2) Consider just `min` instead of `min % 60`. So when the time goes over 1 hour, the minutes will continue 60, 61, … instead of going back to 0. I think it will be less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps.  The remainders weren't being computed correctly.

- For `12340 hundreds` of seconds that would be `123.40 seconds`
- so `12340 / 6000` = `2` for minutes
- `12340 % 6000` gets what's left which is `340`
- so `340 /100` =    `3` seconds
- leaving  `340 % 100`= `40` hundredths

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // n = 16 mins 4 seconds and 99 hundredths
    int n = (16 * 6000) + (4 * 100) + 99;
    System.out.println(convertTimeToText(n));
}

private static String convertTimeToText(int time) {
    int mins = time / 6000;
    time %= 6000; // get remaining hundredths
    int seconds = time / 100;
    int hundredths = time %= 100; // get remaining hundredths

    // format the time.  The leading 0's mean to pad single
    // digits on the left with 0.  The 2 is a field width
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", mins, seconds,
            hundredths);
}
```

This prints

```
16:04:99
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use the standard library

Your timer isn’t accurate. Your observed delay comes from there. Read the time off some clock each time rather than adding 1/100 second. Use for example `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `System.nanoTime()` or `Instant.now()`. Keep the reading from when your stopwatch was started and subtract for getting the current stopwatch value.

Should performing a system call 100 times per second be too expensive (which I don’t expect), do it for example for every 30 ticks to adjust your stopwatch back to the correct time.

Next if you are using Java 9 or higher, use the `Duration` class for converting from the the time (whether in milliseconds or nanoseconds) to minutes and seconds. If you do the conversion by hand as you tried, it’s error-prone and hard to read, which — I believe — was one reason for your question.

For example:

```
    long millisNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Duration time = Duration.ofMillis(millisNow - timeMillisWhenStarted);

    String convertedTime = String.format("%d:%02d.%02d",
            time.toMinutes(), time.toSecondsPart(), time.toMillisPart() / 10);
```